# How to remove character and space from a string

Tags: text-processing

Hello I have one file with output

```
Name        : ABC
Name        : CDE
Name        : ZYS
```

I want to get the result

```
ABC
CDE
ZYS
```

How can i get it through SED command.

I have tried. `sed s/'Name'` but it returns me the output like`: ABC`

I want to trim the space and also `:` from the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{print $3}' yourfile
```

This simply prints the third field/column for every record/row.

Answer (score 3):

If you use sed:

> sed 's/^.*: //' yourfile

or to be a bit more precise:

> sed 's/^Name[^:]*: //' yourfile

Comment: take care, the first one is greedy and eats too much if there's a `': '` in the part right of the first `':'`.

Answer (score 3):

With recent GNU grep versions you could do it like this with positive lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=: ).*' infile
```

Or more portably:

```
grep -o ':.*' infile | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

Output:

```
ABC
CDE
ZYS
```

Answer (score 3):

To complete the other answers with another way:

```
cat file | cut -d: -f 2-
```

you can cut out the remaining whitespace

```
cat file | cut -d: -f 2- | cut -c 2-
```

Or more compact, a bit less readable:

```
cut -d: -f 2- < file | cut -c 2-
```

Comment: No need to use cat here. `cut -d: -f 2- file` works.

Comment: good point, thamks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `awk` command below:

```
awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```